# Measuring distance from point to surface with raycasts

Tags: python, 3d, blender, raycasting

I am trying to measure the distance from a given point to each of the vertices in a mesh, as well as get the point of intersection with a mesh contained within the mesh I am measuring vertex distances to.

I start up a new blender file, and delete the default objects. I then create a cylinder, and a circle, and scale the circle up by a factor of two. I select first the circle, then the cylinder, and run the following script. I get the output:

```
31.999999889172614
127.99999830127179
```

I then select both objects, and translate them in the x direction by one. I select the circle, then the cylinder, and run the script again, giving the following output:

```
0.154086219612509
127.99999919534139
```

The second number's variation I put down to the raycast being slightly imprecise, as it never changes too much. The first number, however, changes wildly based on where I move the objects, which is what has me confused.

```
import bpy
import mathutils
import bmesh

def bmesh_copy_from_object(obj):
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)

    bm.transform(obj.matrix_world)

    return bm

inner = bpy.context.object
outer = (ob for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects if ob != inner).__next__()

inner_bm = bmesh_copy_from_object(inner)
outer_bm = bmesh_copy_from_object(outer)

inner_tree = mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.FromBMesh(inner_bm)
outer_tree = mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.FromBMesh(outer_bm)

cl = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location

innermw = inner.matrix_world
innermw_inv = innermw.inverted()

sum = 0

for v in outer_bm.verts:
    origin = innermw_inv * cl 
    dest = innermw_inv * v.co
    direc = (dest - origin).normalized()

    res, co, no, index = inner_tree.ray_cast(origin, direc)
    if res:
        co_adj = innermw * co
        between = co_adj.dot(co_adj)
        sum += between
    else:
        print(res)

print(sum)

sum = 0

for v in outer_bm.verts:
    vec = v.co - cl
    between = vec.dot(vec)
    sum += between

print(sum)
```

I would expect that both numbers stay exactly the same, as I'm merely translating the shapes without any scaling. Clearly I'm misunderstanding what it is going on with the raycast. I have tried plotting empties at the origin/destination locations, and this has not at all helped my understanding.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're trying to get? You need to get points into the same space, but you don't seem to be using `outer` object transform. It isn't clear why you need cursor position here, or if you move cursor with your objects.

Comment: I'm trying to have a line projected from the cursor location to each of the vertices. I'm trying to find the length of that line that goes from i) The cursor location to the surface of the inner object, ii) The cursor location to the vertex location.

My end goal here is to measure how close a general surface is to another: these distances were merely my metric to do so, but I can't seem to make heads/tails of what raycasting is actually doing.

Comment: The Pythagorean theory [translates to 3D](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77731/935) and is incorporated into [blenders matutils](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94497/935) as a vectors length. You can find several intersect options in [`mathutils.geometry`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_plane).

Comment: @Chris what's special about cursor location? What if it is outside of "outer" mesh, and outer mesh is big but have very few vertices, so no raycast hitting inner geometry? Not mentioning that raycasts from some unknown cursor location towards each vertex are unlikely to reveal true shortest distance between surfaces. When moving objects but not cursor angle of rays shifts, which may produce very different results. If all of that is ok, move calculation to the same space (e.g. world).